# Entity framework with column that may or may not exist

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework that needs to be run against slightly different schemas of a database.

In one database a column does not exist,but in another it is a required (not null) field.

If I was writing SQL, I could query sys.columns to see if the columns exist and adjust my sql accordingly.

How would I do the same with Entity Framework?

Comment: I assume you're using code-first?

Comment: you can write a stored procedure which does a SELECT * for example, this will return all the fields in the table.

Comment: If it's only querying (no insert/update) you can create a VIEW in the database and map against that. In the database where you do not have the column still include it in the view but hard code the value. Alternatively you have to create a model per table schema and keep code segregated where there is a difference so they make use of their own respective models.

Comment: I am using database first.  I need to do updates / inserts.  Adding any new views / stored procedures would not be ideal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework check if column exists during OnModelCreating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754364/entity-framework-check-if-column-exists-during-onmodelcreating)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the column exists then, if does not exists mark it as ignored via fluent API mapping

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>() 
  .Ignore(_ => _.MyOptProperty);
```

Comment: I am using database first so I don't think this will quite work for me.  Any suggestions on how to do something similar with database first?  Maybe I shouldn't be using database first?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use database first so I think that no one does :). In this case you could think about using code first from database.

Comment: Thanks, I think using code first from database is the solution.

Comment: This related answer also explains how to check if the column exists: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60754364/7108481