# check if property Id exists in fluent EF Core configuration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

In the EF Core 5 fluent config, I put the property ID to have the name PropertyName+Id, for all the tables... except the tables that does not have a property named "Id"... How to check if a type does not have such a property?

```
// make the Id column be "EntityName+Id"
foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name)
        .ToTable(entity.DisplayName())
        .Property("Id").HasColumnName(entity.GetTableName() + "Id"); // check first if 'Id' exists
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create the {TableName}+Id column for a class that doesn't have an Id property? Or are you trying to not configure an Id column for those classes?

Comment: Hi @Serge,you can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754364/entity-framework-check-if-column-exists-during-onmodelcreating) may helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work, not sure if its the optimal way

```
foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    var builderEntity = modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name);
    
    // make table name as entity name
    builderEntity.ToTable(entity.DisplayName()); 

    // check if "Id" property exists                      <<<
    if (entity.FindProperty("Id") != null)
    {
        // make Id column name to be tableName+Id
        builderEntity.Property("Id")
            .HasColumnName(entity.GetTableName() + "Id");
    }
}
```